# File is not a zip file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, data-processing

I try to open a file with openpyxl but only get the error:

`raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file") zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`

A simple code example:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('path.xlsx')
```

**Context:** I am trying to open an existing excel file, edit the file and then save it. Until now I am able to only read the file with `pandas.read_excel(path.xlsx)`.

Comment: Try opening it with a zipfile utility and see what it says. The error message might in fact be correct. And make sure the Excel process that created it has closed it.

Comment: Make sure that the xlsx file is not already open in Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The excel files were in *read-only* mode. I saved the file as a new file and load_workbook worked.

Comment: If this happens again, you may also be able to use the ```read_only=True``` argument to ```load_workbook```.

Comment: @sj95126 That is not the case.